# List.BinarySearch Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I search in my list with already sorted data like this:

```
public class ShortWord: IComparable<ShortWord>
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(ShortWord obj)
    {
       return this.Word.CompareTo(obj.Word);
    }
}

List<ShortWord> words;
words.Where(t => t.Word.IndexOf(text.ToUpper()) == 0).Take(30).ToList();
```

It is working very slowly. I think need use List.BinarySearch but I don't understand how can I use it for my example.

I trying implement something but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since compare is based on the word, you can create new instance with input word and pass it to the [BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
List<ShortWord> words;
int index = words.BinarySearch(new ShortWord() {
     Word = text,
};
if (index >= 0) {
  ShortWord result = words[index];
}
```

Accoring to MSDN, BinarySearch will use the implemented [IComparable.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> This method uses the default comparer Comparer.Default for type T
>   to determine the order of list elements. The Comparer.Default
>   property checks whether type T implements the IComparable generic
>   interface and uses that implementation, if available. If not,
>   Comparer.Default checks whether type T implements the IComparable
>   interface. If type T does not implement either interface,
>   Comparer.Default throws an InvalidOperationException.

**Edit:**

If you may have multiple items with the same word in the list, you should iterate the list from index until you get an item with different word.

Comment: I  used your example but I always have negative values

Comment: @romandrovich your compare method is case-sensitive, did you consider that?

Comment: yes.   new ShortWord() { Word = text.ToUpper() } And in my words all already ToUpper()

Comment: Yes!It wasn't sorted. But I search word which start with "text". How I should change my **CompareTo** method?

Comment: @romandrovich you can compare only first n characters in CompareTo method but I dont think in makes much sense. You should use a custom comparer in that case, or maybe not using the BinarySearch and use the Linq method.